# How to get recent folder history in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to get a list of recently accessed folders. How to implement it?

Comment: Which part is difficult?  All you have to do is to create an array of file paths and then pass it to a menu.

Comment: If it is possible to get recent folders history by code?

Answer (score 2):

`Finder` stores the items from the `Recent Folders` menu in:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

This information is not meant for other applications, so the format may change without notice.

Still, you can retrieve the list using `NSUserDefaults` or `CFPreferences`.

The following code works in Yosemite. I haven't included any error-checking:

```
//Read the latest changes.
CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(CFSTR("com.apple.finder"));

//Retrieve the folder list.
NSArray* folderList = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)
                            CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(CFSTR("FXRecentFolders"), CFSTR("com.apple.finder"));
for (NSDictionary* currentFolder in folderList) {

    //Print name.
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [currentFolder objectForKey:@"name"]);

    //Print path.
    NSURL* folderURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:[currentFolder objectForKey:@"file-bookmark"]
                                                 options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI |
                                                         NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutMounting
                                           relativeToURL:nil
                                     bookmarkDataIsStale:nil
                                                   error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Path: %@", [folderURL path]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks~it's working well